# How can you be DRY with a programming language that doesn't have Reflection?

Tags: c, reflection, aop, dry

Any programming language that does not have a suitable reflection mechanism I find seriously debilitating for rapidly changing problems.

It seems with certain languages its incredible hard or not possible to do:

- **Convention over Configuration**
- **Automatic Databinding**
- **AOP / Meta programming**

with out reflection.

Some example languages that do not have some sort of programmatic reflection are:
**C, C++, Haskell, OCaml**. I'm sure there are plenty more.

To show you can example of DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) being violated by most of these languages is when you have to write Unit Tests. You almost always need to register your test cases in these languages outside of where you define the test.

How do programmers of these languages mitigate this problem?

EDIT: Common languages that do have reflection for those that do not know are: C#, Java, Python, Ruby, and my personal favorite F# and Scala.

EDIT: The two common approaches it seems are [code instrumentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_%28computer_programming%29) and code generation. However I have never seen instrumentation for C.

**Instead of just voting to close, could some one please comment on why this should be closed and I'll delete the post.**

Comment: we don't.  I repeat myself all the time in C.

Comment: @AShelly why would you continue to bang your head or stub your toe against the wall :) Can you change your language to something else?

Comment: I'm curious which languages can do all of those things so well?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Most languages used for Web App dev like C#,Java, Python, Ruby and my personal favorite F# since its kind of the first statically typed FP to have reflection.

Comment: @Adam Gent: my experience with Java (CLI, desktop apps, and web apps) is that it does NONE of those things very well - at least not by itself. Those features are usually given by frameworks, not by the language itself. FYI, there *are* AOP frameworks for C++. Probably for other languages too. I am not an expert on Ruby, but I thought that "Convention over Configuration" was a main feature of Rails (a framework), not of Ruby.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner but its at least possible in those languages. BTW JAXB serializes any Java POJO into XML and its built into Java 1.6. I cannot say the same for the languages I listed.

Comment: @Adam Gent:  I do use Ruby for rapid development, but when it comes to real-time embedded programming, C is the standard my employer insists on.  I can mitigate some of the repetition with macros and pointers to structures, but in the end I still end up with multiple copies of very similar code.

Comment: I know you're probably not asking about web languages, but it's possible to create amazingly syntactically concise API's with PHP especially if you use reflection. Java is `justALostCauseInMyHonestOpinionIfYouWantSomethingEasyToType`.

Comment: @Byron Its also amazing simple to type that method with a code completion IDE like eclipse. And unlike PHP its amazingly easy to then refactor that method with the IDE. Java used to suck big time with out IDEs. Now its much better.

Comment: @Adam Gent I also forgot to mention readability. When I'm reading Java code I feel like I'm reading an essay. With PHP, I can update my site from my phone because you need little more than a text editor. With Java, I would die without an IDE.

Comment: @Byron I'm not defending Java here. It sucks for conciseness (didn't you see how I said I liked F# better)

Comment: @Adam Gent: serializing into XML is good and useful, but that's a function of an included library, not the language itself. As for AOP, Could you tell me which language can implement AOP without any extra libraries? I am not aware of them - but if they are out there, I would very much like to try them out.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I am not positive but I believe Lisp has some AOP-like things built in (atleast common lisp).

Answer (score 3):

You don't.
But you can keep the repetitions close to each other so when changing something, you see something else has to be changed too.

For example, I wrote a JSON-Parser that outputs objects, a typical call looks like this:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
        int a;
        int b;
        double c;

        typedef int serializable;
        template<class SerializerT> void serialize(SerializerT& s)
        {
                s("a",a)("b",b)("c",c);
        }
};
```

Sure, when you add a field, you have to add another field in the function, but maybe you don't want to serialize that field (something you'd have to handle in languages with reflection, too), and if you delete a field without removing it from the function, the compiler will complain.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix the Unit Test problem. +1 for the answer

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a matter of degree.  Reflection is just one very powerful method of avoiding repetition.

Any time you generalize a function from a specific case you are using DRY principle, the more general you make it the more DRY it is.  Just because some languages don't get you where you get with reflection doesn't mean there aren't DRY ways of programming with them.  They may not be as DRY, but that doesn't mean they don't have their own unique advantages which in total sum may outweigh the advantages of using a language that has reflection.  (For example, speed consequences from heavy use of reflection could be a consideration.)

Also, one method of getting something like the DRY benefits of reflection with a language that doesn't support it is by using a good code-generation tool.  In that case you modify the code for different cases once, in the code generation template, and the template pushes it out to different instances in code.  (I'm not saying whether or not using code generation is a good thing, but with a good "active" generator it is certainly one way of getting something like the DRY benefit of reflection in a language that doesn't have reflection.  And the benefits of code generation go beyond this simple benefit.  I'm thinking of something like CodeSmith, although there are many others: http://www.codesmithtools.com/ )

Answer (score 2):

1. Abstractly, do more at runtime, without the benefits of things like compile-time type checking (you have to essentially write your own type-checking routines) and beautiful code.  E.g., use a table instead of a class.  (But if you did this, why not use a dynamically-typed language instead?)  **This is often bad.  I do not recommend this.**
2. In C++, generic programming techniques allow you to programmatically include members of a class (is that what you want to do?) via inheritance.

Comment: Aye.  Option 1 is essentially applying the old "Anything can be solved with another level of indirection." maxim.

Answer (score 1):

One nice example for C++ unit testing is cxxtest:
http://cxxtest.tigris.org/. It uses convention and a python script to generate your C++ test suite by post-processing your C++ with python.

A good way to think about getting around restrictions in languages is Michael Feathers' notion of "seams". A seam is a place where your program can be changed without changing the code. For example, in C the pre-processor and linker provide seams. In C++ polymorphism is another place. In more dynamic languages like where you can change method definitions, or reflect, you get even more flexibility. Without the seams things can be more complicated and sometimes you just don't want to try to hammer a nail with your shoe but rather go with the flow of the tool at hand.

Comment: @paulrubel I get a feeling that preprocessing is what these languages do. Some people think reflection is code smell. I think preprocessing is far worse. +1 for the link

Comment: The thing that saves the day here is that the results of the python script are regenerated each time they are needed, it's not like a wizard where you keep the generated code around and need to modify it.

Comment: @paulrubel Ill have to check out "seams". I wish I could give you another +1 for your excellent edit.

Comment: @Adam: Preprocessing worse than reflection? But where does reflection data come from? Preprocessing.

Comment: @Zan Lynx I might be missing something but I mean compiler preprocessing like the C Pre Processor. I guess what you are saying is the compiler adds meta data to the type (ie reified types) could be counted as preprocessing.

Comment: @Adam: Yes, exactly. In C/C++ it is still *called* a preprocessor but all compilers I know of integrate that into the compiler so it isn't really "pre" anything. So I would rate Java's reflection generation as being at the same processing stage.